# multiply dataframes based on timestamp intervals overlap

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, numexpr

I have two pandas dataframes, each with two columns: a measurement and a timestamp. I need to multiply the first differences of the measurements, but only if there is a time overlap between the two measurement intervals. How can I do this efficiently, as the size of the dataframes gets large?
Example:

```
dfA
      mesA   timeA
0     125    2015-01-14 04:44:49     
1     100    2015-01-14 05:16:23
2     115    2015-01-14 08:57:10     

dfB
      mesB    timeB
0     140     2015-01-14 00:13:17
1     145     2015-01-14 08:52:01
2     120     2015-01-14 11:31:44
```

Here I would multiply `(100-125)*(145-140)` since there is a time overlap between the intervals `[04:44:49, 05:16:23]` and `[00:13:17, 08:52:01]`, but not `(100-125)`and`(120-145)`, since there isn't one. Similarly, I would have `(115-100)*(145-140)` but also `(115-100)*(120-145)`, since both have a time overlap.

In the end I will have to sum all the relevant products in a single value, so the result need not be a dataframe. In this case:

```
s = (100-125)*(145-140)+(115-100)*(145-140)+(115-100)*(120-145) = -425
```

My current solution:

```
s = 0
for i in range(1, len(dfA)):
    startA = dfA['timeA'][i-1]
    endA = dfA['timeA'][i]
    for j in range(1, len(dfB)):
        startB = dfB['timeB'][j-1]
        endB = dfB['timeB'][j]
        if (endB>startA) & (startB<endA):
            s+=(dfA['mesA'][i]-dfA['mesA'][i-1])*(dfB['mesB'][j]-dfB['mesB'][j-1])
```

Although it seems to work, it is very inefficient and becomes impractical with very large datasets. I believe it could be vectorized more efficiently, perhaps using `numexpr`, but I still haven't found a way.

EDIT:
other data

```
    mesA  timeA
0   125   2015-01-14 05:54:03
1   100   2015-01-14 11:39:53
2   115   2015-01-14 23:58:13
    mesB  timeB
0   110   2015-01-14 10:58:32
1   120   2015-01-14 13:30:00
2   135   2015-01-14 22:29:26

s = 125
```

Comment: I need only the sum, fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: the original answer did not work, so I came up with another version that is not vectorize but they need to be sorted by date.

```
arrA = dfA.timeA.to_numpy()
startA, endA = arrA[0], arrA[1]
arr_mesA = dfA.mesA.diff().to_numpy()
mesA = arr_mesA[1]

arrB = dfB.timeB.to_numpy()
startB, endB = arrB[0], arrB[1]
arr_mesB = dfB.mesB.diff().to_numpy()
mesB = arr_mesB[1]

s = 0
i, j = 1, 1
imax = len(dfA)-1
jmax = len(dfB)-1
while True:
    if (endB>startA) & (startB<endA):
        s+=mesA*mesB
    if (endB>endA) and (i<imax):
        i+=1
        startA, endA, mesA= endA, arrA[i], arr_mesA[i]
    elif j<jmax:
        j+=1
        startB, endB, mesB = endB, arrB[j], arr_mesB[j]
    else:
        break
```

Original not working answer

The idea is to great category with `pd.cut` based on the value in `dfB['timeB']` in both dataframes to see where they could overlap. Then calculate the `diff` in measurements. `merge` both dataframes on categories and finally multiply and `sum` the whole thing

```
# create bins
bins_dates = [min(dfB['timeB'].min(), dfA['timeA'].min())-pd.DateOffset(hours=1)]\
             + dfB['timeB'].tolist()\
             + [max(dfB['timeB'].max(), dfA['timeA'].max())+pd.DateOffset(hours=1)]

# work on dfB
dfB['cat'] = pd.cut(dfB['timeB'], bins=bins_dates,
                    labels=range(len(bins_dates)-1), right=False)
dfB['deltaB'] = -dfB['mesB'].diff(-1).ffill()

# work on dfA
dfA['cat'] = pd.cut(dfA['timeA'], bins=bins_dates,
                    labels=range(len(bins_dates)-1), right=False)
# need to calcualte delta for both start and end of intervals
dfA['deltaAStart'] = -dfA['mesA'].diff(-1)
dfA['deltaAEnd'] = dfA['mesA'].diff().mask(dfA['cat'].astype(float).diff().eq(0))
# in the above method, for the end of interval, use a mask to not count twice 
# intervals that are fully included in one interval of B

# then merge and calcualte the multiplication you are after
df_ = dfB[['cat', 'deltaB']].merge(dfA[['cat','deltaAStart', 'deltaAEnd']])
s = (df_['deltaB'].to_numpy()[:,None]*df_[['deltaAStart', 'deltaAEnd']]).sum().sum()
print (s)
#-425.0
```

Comment: it works! I simply made it in a function and added `@njit()` from `numba` and could easily handle very large datasets, thanks!

Comment: @therealcode yes numba will easily speed up all this :)